# Passing string array from one activity to another

Tags: android, arrays, bundle

hi i am passing a string array from one activity to another, I am getting the length of array in the next activity correct but when i am trying to use that array i am getting null value my code is below:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
         Log.e("jjhj",""+position);
         Bitmap imageBitmap=bmp[position];
         Log.e("image",""+bmp[position]);
         ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         imageBitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG,100, byteArrayOutputStream);
         byte[] image = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

         Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewFullImage.class);

        // passing array index
       // i.putExtra("image", image);
        bundle.putStringArray("imagearray",imageGallaryArray);
        bundle.putInt("imageposition",position);;

        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Next Activity :

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.viewgallaryfull);
           // getImages();

            Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
            position=bundle.getInt("imageposition");
            Log.e("position",""+position);
            //String [] imagegal=new String[500];
            String [] imagegal=bundle.getStringArray("imagearray");
            int length=imagegal.length;
            Log.e("length",""+length);
            Log.e("hut",""+imagegal[1]);
            for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
            {
                Log.e("image",imagegal[i]);
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("image",imagegal[i]);
                MyArrList.add(map);
            }
```

Comment: can you post the logcat output.

Comment: @ShivamVerma:06-20 04:23:29.490: E/position(1623): 0
06-20 04:23:29.490: E/length(1623): 5
06-20 04:23:29.490: E/hut(1623): null

Comment: A bit more maybe ? Something which includes the line number where the NPE is occuring and it'd be great if you could point out that line in the code. just to be sure.

Comment: theres no null pointer exception i m jus getting value as null of  imagegal[1]

Comment: In that case, make sure that the array you are passing has the correct values. Maybe just log the values before passing the array.

Comment: @ShivamVerma: checked correct

Comment: Before startActivity add log to check which values are in the array. Your code looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution looks pretty simple to me. The way you describe it either the array itself you are handing over to the next `Activity` or the String values inside the array **are null**. **This is not an issue of transferring data** between `Activities`.

**Make sure your array and its values are not null**, and your problem will be solved.

Comment: the array i passed is  not null and m also getting the length of arrray

Answer (score 0):

If the length itself is OK and you don't get a NullReferenceException i expect that the values of the array or at least one of them is NULL.

Consequently check the creation and storage of your values into the array in the first activity. The way you pass the String array is absolutely correct.

---

**EDIT:** Having considered your creation code

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) { 
    imageGallaryArray=new String[jArray.length()]; // PROBLEM HERE!
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
    imageGallary=json_data.getString("image"); 
    imageGallaryArray[i]=json_data.getString("image"); 
    Log.e("imagegallarysdf",""+imageGallaryArray[i]);
}
```

You recreate imageGallaryArray in each iteration. Adjust your code like this:

```
imageGallaryArray=new String[jArray.length()]; // MOVED UP; Once created and now filled properly
map = new HashMap<String, String>(); // Unused, but why recreate it on each iteration again?

for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) { 
    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    imageGallary=json_data.getString("image"); 
    imageGallaryArray[i]=json_data.getString("image"); 
    Log.e("imagegallarysdf",""+imageGallaryArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: i have checked the value in first activity they are correct and its returning null at ever index

Comment: Could you please post the creation code of the string array and also evaluate with your debugger, whether the array values are indeed null or if logcat just causes problems, setting a breakpoint to the line after `getStringArray`and checking the values manually.

Comment: The creation code of the string array to be passed from the first activity to the second.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
    {
     imageGallaryArray=new String[jArray.length()];
     json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     imageGallary=json_data.getString("image");
     imageGallaryArray[i]=json_data.getString("image");
     Log.e("imagegallarysdf",""+imageGallaryArray[i]);

Comment: :thank you for the optimization but the problem is not in my first activity as the array i am passing is perfectly ok i have checked it..the problem is with another activity

Comment: if i m putting hashmap initialization outside the loop its displaying only one image so i need to put it inside loop...

Comment: @Neha, you are initialising the string array inside for loop. Do that above the for loop. It is creating new string array each time

Comment: @JijuInduchoodan: i have already specified above that the problem is not in the first activity but second..

Comment: @JijuInduchoodan: itz the same answer you pasted earlier

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can consider using [Intent.getStringArrayExtra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayExtra%28java.lang.String%29)

In the first activity:

```
final ArrayList<String> country = new ArrayList<String>();
    country.add("INDIA");
    country.add( "pak");
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ABC.class);
            intent.putExtra("string-array", country);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

On Second Activity

```
Bundle i=getIntent().getExtras();
         if(i!=null){
                ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>)i.getStringArrayList("string-array");
         tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv.setText(""+arr);
}
```

Comment: thanks aman but i m using json parsing and i have already done this work using hashmap and i want to use this array in hashmap in next activity...

Comment: @Neha then please accept the answer, to help others as well.

Comment: none of the answer here resolved my problem...i used some alternate method.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resides inside the code itself.
Change like this

```
    imageGallaryArray=new String[jArray.length()]; 
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) 
    { 
     json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
     map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
     imageGallary=json_data.getString("image"); 
     imageGallaryArray[i]=json_data.getString("image");   
     Log.e("imagegallarysdf",""+imageGallaryArray[i]); 
    }
```